# memory leak in django shell, django rest framework serializer and cassandra

Tags: python, django, cassandra

I have a django cassandra model like this:

```
class Milad(DjangoCassandraModel):
name = columns.Text(primary_key=True)
bulkid = columns.BigInt(primary_key=True)
f1 = columns.UUID()
f2 = columns.UUID()
f3 = columns.UUID()
f4 = columns.UUID()
f5 = columns.UUID()
f6 = columns.UUID()
f7 = columns.UUID()
f8 = columns.UUID()
f9 = columns.UUID()
f10 = columns.UUID()

class Meta:
    get_pk_field = "bulkid"
```

and following serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class BulkidSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    bulkid = serializers.IntegerField()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return instance.bulkid
```

I have 220200 records in my table.
when i open the django shell with command `python3 manage.py shell`
a do the following operations my memory usage from 8.8GB goes to 10.8GB.

operations:

```
records = Milad.objects.all().limit(None)
data = BulkidSerializer(records, many=True).data
```

after the operation when i use `sys.getsizeof(data)`
the size of the object is about 2MB but my memory is still 10.8 when no operation is running and no data with that size is in my memory till i close the shell.
what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Materializing all results in memory at one point will cause memory usage to spike. It is not uncommon for the Python runtime to expand memory and not return it to the OS immediately. It should not be cause for concern unless you are bumping into resource limits.

If you want to avoid materializing all results in memory, you should use paging provided by the driver.

[By token with cqlengine](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.17/cqlengine/queryset/#token-function)

[Paging in driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.17/query_paging/)